# DOM elements not accessible after onsen pageinit in ons.ready

Tags: jquery-selectors, onsen-ui

I am using the Onsen framework with jQuery and jQuery mobile, it appears that there is no way to catch the event that fires once the new page is loaded.

My current code, which executes in the index.html file (the master page)

```
<script src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script> 
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();
      ons.ready(function() {

        $(document.body).on('pageinit', '#recentPage', function() {
            initRecentPage();
        });


});
```

in app.js is the following code

```
function initRecentPage() {

$("#yourReports").on("tap", ".showReport", recentShowReport);
var content = document.getElementById("yourReports");
ons.compile(content);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<ons-page id="recentPage"> 
<ons-toolbar id="myToolbar">        
        <div id="toolBarTitle" class="center">Recent Checks</div>
         <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="mySlidingMenu.toggleMenu()">
                <ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-scroller>

<h3 class="headingTitle"> Checks</h3>
<div id="Free" class="tabArea">

<ons-list id="yourReports">
</ons-list>
<ons-button id="clearFreeRecentButton">
<span id="clearRecentText" class="bold">Clear Recent Checks</span>  
</ons-button>
</div>

</ons-scroller>
</ons-page>
```

in this instance the variable 'content' is always null. I've debuged significantly, and the element I am trying to get is not present when this event fires. It is loaded later.

So, the question is, how do I ensure that all of the content is present before using a selector. It feels like this is an onsen specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I could only find one reliable way of making this work.
Essentially I had to wait, using setTimeout 300 milliseconds for the DOM elements to be ready. It feels like a hack, but honestly there is no other reliable way of making this behave. The app is in the app store and works well, so even though it seems like a hack, it works:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '#homePage', function() {
        initHomePage();
    });

function initHomePage() {
 setTimeout(function() {
    setUpHomePage();
 }, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `$(document.body).on('pageinit', '#recentPage', function() {` outside of `ons.ready` block.

**JS**

```
ons.bootstrap();
ons.ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
});

$(document.body).on('pageinit', '#recentPage', function() {
            initRecentPage();
 });

function initRecentPage() {

//$("#yourReports").on("tap", ".showReport", recentShowReport);
var content = document.getElementById("yourReports");
  alert(content)
ons.compile(content);
}
```

I commented out a line because I do not have access to that "recentShowReport"

You can see how it works here: 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/xCqDe'

The alert will show that 'content' is not NULL.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this doesn't work either. I see how this works in the codepen, but in a multipage application (im building using monaca), this doesnt work.
If i move the code outside the ons.ready, nothing fires at all. At least inside the ons.ready function I got a callback, even though the DOM element wasnt loaded correctly.
I'm trying to see if it has anything to do with the way the page is opened, currently it is opened by- ySlidingMenu.setMainPage('recent.html', {closeMenu: true}), maybe this is interferring with the DOM loading. The lack of docs is a pain.

Comment: It should work... maybe it was cached? I do it all the time on my multipages project on Monaca as well..

Comment: Thanks again Vu for your help. The issue is not solved but I've discovered a few things. If I change the $(document.body).on function to $(document).on the callback fires, strange eh.
Secondly, I think the issue has something to do with the way the page is opening. Its being opened from the menu via a call to - ySlidingMenu.setMainPage('recent.html', {closeMenu: true}). Now, this triggers the callback but the html element is not present. I think it has something to do with the way the menu hides then shows content. If I put in a simple setTimeout and wait 100 milliseconds, the element is there